# Where is FormsAuthenticationModule registered?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

Now I'm trying to find out how asp.net mvc authentication works in details. As I understand exactly FormsAuthenticationModule checks cookie and fills up HttpContext.User. But I can't find where FormsAuthenticationModule is registered for my application?

Comment: It's registered on web server level. Let's say you host on IIS, go to IIS Manager, select top level and click Modules, and you will find it there

Comment: And depends on authentication type (windows or forms) iis calls appropriate auth module (WindowsAuthenticationModule or FormsAuthenticationModule)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I can't find where FormsAuthenticationModule is registered for my application?

It's automatically registered by the ASP.NET runtime when you set `<authentication mode="Forms">` in your web.config.

If you are interested in the details, you may take a look at the source code of ASP.NET and more specifically the `HttpApplication` class and the `InitModulesCommon` private method which is calling the `Init` method of the FormsAuthentication module if you registered it in your web.config.

The FormsAuthentication module itself, once registered, will subscribe to the `AuthenticateRequest` event of the HTTP processing pipeline and it will attempt to build an IPrincipal into the current HttpContext based on the values present in the forms authentication cookie sent in the request.

Comment: Does formsauthenticationmodule use registered in application membership provider to get data about user?

Comment: No, Forms Authentication has absolutely nothing to do with the Membership provider. Those are 2 completely different things that could be used independently.

Comment: How does module get username?

Comment: It reads it from the Forms Authentication cookie that the browser sends on each request. When you emit a forms authentication cookie using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` static method, this will encrypt the username using the machine keys in a cookie. This cookie will be sent on each subsequent request, the Forms Authentication module will check for its presence, attempt to decrypt it and if it succeeds, it will populate the HttpContext.User property. Please read the following article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx which describes the entire flow in lots of details.

Answer (score 8):

It's inherited from root web.config. For example, if you have .NET 4 installed on x64 machine open `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config`. In `system.web` section you'll find the following modules registered:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="OutputCache" type="System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule" />
    <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
    <add name="WindowsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule" />
    **<add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />**
    <add name="PassportAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.PassportAuthenticationModule" />
    <add name="RoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule" />
    <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />
    <add name="FileAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule" />
    <add name="AnonymousIdentification" type="System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule" />
    <add name="Profile" type="System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule" />
    <add name="ErrorHandlerModule" type="System.Web.Mobile.ErrorHandlerModule, System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
    <add name="ScriptModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</httpModules>
```

ASP.NET merges it with all `web.config` files it finds down the hierarchy on file system so applications have all the modules enabled by default.